# the lawmakers went on television/radio

Tags: word-meaning, word-in-context

> Apr 14, 2015
>
> Not "use"; more like "go to (or into, or on to)". For example, "The protesters took to the streets to spread their message"; or "The villagers took to the hills to avoid the invading army".
>
> So, in your case, the lawmakers **went** on television/radio.
>
> I suspect that "take to", in this sense, may be a shortening of "take oneself to" — though I can't find any firm proof of that.

[Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/take-to-the-airwaves.2999306/)

---

The word *go* has so many senses.
Which sense matches the use of "**went**"?

Comment: Possibly _travel or move in order to engage in a specified activity_?

Comment: "[to take a certain course or follow a certain procedure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go)" in Merriam-Webster fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lawmakers could have **taken to the airwaves** to be on television and radio. In this context, **airwaves** specifically means *broadcasting on television and radio* ([reference](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/airwaves)).

Other similar, and perhaps more common idioms are:

- hit the airwaves - be broadcast for the first time
- rule the airwaves - receive more broadcasting time than others

There are many different ways you can be on television or radio. The most common are probably **go** and **be**

- go on television
- be on television

[Here is a nice list](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/go) of many different ways that **go** is used. One of the examples happens to be "go on television."